# C# Working with big Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm using an `Intel.RealSense` 3D camera which return a big array with depth distances of an image.
If camera is rotated I have to rotate the image, and finally I want to save those values in files.

The array from `Intel.RealSense` api is single dimension ushort array with all rows concatenated. So my first step is convert it to Two Dimension Array and multiply each value by scale to have distance values in correct scale.

```
private void FillRawDepth()
{
    _depthData = new float[_frameDimension.Height, _frameDimension.Width];
    for (int row = 0; row < _frameDimension.Height; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < _frameDimension.Width; column++)
        {
            var idx = (row * _frameDimension.Width) + column;
            _depthData[row, column] = _depthFrameRawData[idx] * _frameDimension.DepthScale;
        }
    }
}
```

For this step it takes aprox. 10ms.

After that I have some method Extensions to rotate matrix (this method takes aprox. 10ms)

```
public static float[,] DoRotation(this float[,] sourceMatrix, Rotation rotation)
{
    switch (rotation)
    {
        case Rotation.Rotate0:
            return sourceMatrix;

        case Rotation.Rotate90:
            return MatrixRotation90(sourceMatrix);

        case Rotation.Rotate180:
            return MatrixRotation180(sourceMatrix);

        case Rotation.Rotate270:
            return MatrixRotation270(sourceMatrix);

        default:
            return sourceMatrix;
    }
}

private static float[,] MatrixRotation180(float[,] source)
{
    var rows = source.GetLength(0);
    var columns = source.GetLength(1);
    var rotated = new float[rows, columns];
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            rotated[row, column] = source[rows - row - 1, columns - column - 1];
        }
    }
    return rotated;
}

private static float[,] MatrixRotation90(float[,] source)
{
    var rows = source.GetLength(1);
    var columns = source.GetLength(0);
    var rotated = new float[rows, columns];
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            rotated[row, column] = source[column, row];
        }
    }
    return rotated;
}

private static float[,] MatrixRotation270(float[,] source)
{
    var rows = source.GetLength(1);
    var columns = source.GetLength(0);
    var rotated = new float[rows, columns];
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            rotated[row, column] = source[columns - column - 1, rows - row - 1];
        }
    }
    return rotated;
}
```

Finally I have to save the final matrix to file.

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var depthData = frame.GetRawDepthMatrix(rotation);
    var rows = depthData.GetLength(0);
    var columns = depthData.GetLength(1);
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            writer.Write($"{depthData[row, column]};");
        }
        writer.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The complete process is taking aprox 500 ms. As I have seen the matrix operations are taking only 10-20 ms. So the most expensive method is saving to file. I have try also to build all text in `StringBuilder` ans save the `StringBuilder` to file, but it's similar.

Is my code correct or it can be done better maybe using `Vector` or other collection with better performance? It's possible to reduce the file save method?